# Difference between entity and relation in UML and SQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, uml, entity-relationship

Just wanted to make sure that I'm understanding this right:

- designing UML-diagram we are talking about the relations between entities?
- in the context of SQL a table is a relation?

I can remember that my teacher, for a while ago, was talking about associations between entities which makes me unsure what words are the right way to use in the context of UML-diagrams and SQL.

Words to figure out: entity, relation and association. Contexts: UML and SQL.

Comment: What research did you do already? These are really the core basics of the UML.

Comment: *designing UML-diagram we are talking about the relations between entitys?* The diagram describes the entities and the relations between them. *in the context of SQL a table is a relation?* The table is an entity container which stores an entity instances.

Comment: @Ister I've gone through my notes from university, read posts her in Stackoverflow, viewed pictures on google, read the book: Applying UML and patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **UML** we have **classes** and associations.  There is no entity in the UML specifications, although a popular [class stereotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_(UML)) is [`«entity»`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary):

> an entity represents long-lived information relevant for the stakeholders

which, in other words, generally refer to a set of presistant domain object stored in a database.

In SQL **databases**, we have **tables**.  Tables represent what is called a **relation** in **relational algebra**.   Now database modellers have invented the term of entity that corresponds to a set of relations,  and relationships that correspond to a mapping between entities.

So you mix in your question very different concepts.  However,  there are some similarities:  relational entities correspond to a subset of simple classes without behaviours, and relationships correspond to associations. The field that maps the relational world with classes is called [object-relational mapping (ORM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping).  ORM is a set of techniques that allow to map classes of objects to database tables and associations to relationships, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me start that there is a lot of confusion in the question. There are some terms that are not used in the UML context. So it is critical to build understanding on that.
The answer would have to be too broad for the StackOverflow but let me give a couple of directions that should be sufficient.

First of all, the terminology has to be properly corrected. In UML we do not have a term *Entity*. We have *Elements* that are constituents of the model. The *Elements* are then divided (among others) into *Classifiers* and *Relationships*. The *Classifiers*, while broader than what we typically understand under *Entity* in the SQL context is a good approximation. The most commonly used type of *Classifier* is a *Class*. In most cases an *Entity* in ERD diagram will be represented by a *Class* in the UML Class diagram.

*Relationships* are showing how the *Elements* are related with each other (note, a *Relationship* is also an *Element*). While there are several types of *Relationships*, the most broad type of the *Relationship* between *Classifiers* (and *Classes* for instance) is a *Dependency*. This *Relationship* type shows only, that one *Classifier* requires the other to function. A more precise *Relationship* that is semantically stronger than a *Dependency* is *Association*. In SQL terms only some *Associations* are significant, and those are typically represented as *Foreign Key Constraints*.

I'd say you should go back to reading the Applied UML and Patterns. It is all explained there, with examples. Focus on UML first and ignore the SQL part. Once you get a grasp of it, get back to the relation to SQL.

Comment: By definition - correct. However semantically, the Dependency is the weakest type of Relationship between the Classifiers, whereas the Association is stronger. I've corrected the answer slightly to be more accurate, though I am not sure if that doesn't decrease the clarity.